# Switch between stylesheets css

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Ok I am new in this site and even new in html ,css and javascript.

Like the title says I need help with switching between style sheets.

I did everything I need but there is one thing, switching between style sheets works in internet explorer perfectly, but not in chrome.

What is happening in chrome? I can switch in chrome too and everything works perfectly but not the whole background color changes , only the viewed section become black , then you need to scroll down to change the color of the rest of the page.

It will be nice to get some help.

This is the code.

```js
function darkTheme() {
  var theme = document.getElementById('lightTheme');
  theme.href = "styleSheetDarkTheme.css";
}

function lightTheme() {
  var theme = document.getElementById('lightTheme');
  theme.href = "styleSheetLightTheme.css";
}
```

```css
#option_list {
  height: 40px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
#option1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 0.7291666666666666em;
  margin-right: 0.7291666666666666em;
  background-clip: content-box;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: bold 19px serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.themes {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
#option1:hover {
  background-color: rgb(84, 84, 84);
  color: white;
}
#dropDownMenu {
  position: fixed;
  padding-left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(84, 84, 84);
  width: 190px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
#option1:hover #dropDownMenu {
  display: block;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.themes:hover {
  background-color: rgba(3, 3, 3, 0.51);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link id="lightTheme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleSheetLightTheme.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="option_list">
    <div id="option1">
      Theme
      <ul id="dropDownMenu">
        <li onclick="darkTheme()" class="themes">Dark the</li>
        <li onclick="lightTheme()" class="themes">Light theme</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your lighttheme function does not appear to do anything? It just defines a variable and then changes a non-existing attribute of that variable. It should first target an element and then change it's href.

Comment: @user1129884, my lightTheme function works perfectly, I just forgot to add something in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mistake in your `lightTheme`:

```
function lightTheme() {
  var theme = document.getElementById('lightTheme');
  theme.href = "styleSheetLightTheme.css";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `lighttheme` funtion, change the variable `theme`

```
function lightTheme() {
  var theme = document.getElementById('lightTheme');
  theme.href = "styleSheetLightTheme.css";
}
```

Comment: How does this fix the fact that the `darkTheme()` function doesn't work in chrome as was the actual question?

Comment: Well, where are the stylesheets and the page that they are being used in located?

Comment: @yak613, the stylesheet is located in the same folder of the html file, I have everything in one folder

Answer (score 1):

The `lighttheme` function isn't doing anything.

```
function lightTheme() {
  var theme = document.getElementById('lightTheme');
  theme.href = "styleSheetLightTheme.css";
}

function darkTheme() {
  var theme = document.getElementById('darkTheme');
  theme.href = "styleSheetDarkTheme.css";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one with set cookie valid for 1 day, so it will checks for the style-setting cookie, and if present, switches the style sheets accordingly. Otherwise, it use default style.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="light" href="styleLightTheme.css">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="dark" href="styleDarkTheme.css">

</head>
<body onload="set_style_from_cookie()">
  <div id="option_list">
    <div id="option1">
      Theme
      <ul id="dropDownMenu">
        <li onclick="switch_style('dark'); return false;" class="themes" id="dark">Dark Theme</li>
        <li onclick="switch_style('light'); return false;" class="themes" id="light">Light Theme</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Script:

```
var style_cookie_name = "style" ;
var style_cookie_duration = 30 ;

function switch_style ( css_title )
{
var i, link_tag ;
  for (i = 0, link_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("link") ;
    i < link_tag.length ; i++ ) {
    if ((link_tag[i].rel.indexOf( "stylesheet" ) != -1) &&
      link_tag[i].title) {
      link_tag[i].disabled = true ;
      if (link_tag[i].title == css_title) {
        link_tag[i].disabled = false ;
      }
    }
    set_cookie( style_cookie_name, css_title,
      style_cookie_duration );
  }
}
function set_style_from_cookie()
{
  var css_title = get_cookie( style_cookie_name );
  if (css_title.length) {
    switch_style( css_title );
  }
}

function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value,
    lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
{

    var domain_string = valid_domain ?
                       ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ;
    document.cookie = cookie_name +
                       "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
                       "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
                       24 * lifespan_in_days +
                       "; path=/" + domain_string ;
}

function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
    // 
    var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
    if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
        var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
                        '(^|;)[\s]*' +
                        cookie_name +
                        '=([^;]*)' );
        return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
    }
    return '' ;
}
```